# Why is items list lagging?

Tags: theming, 8

I'm exploring Drupal 8 Twig system.
After I altered menu.html.twig I tried to print out menu items list, but when I load the page after appending `{{ dump( items ) }}` it all stucks, page is not loading, Apache process is at 15% CPU. Why is this happening? Can I somehow print out all item's content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid twig's dump() is a resource killer. You can follow this issue on drupal.org for more information and alternatives: [Twig dump crashes site/server with out of memory](https://www.drupal.org/node/2647298).

My advice would be to use [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)'s kint() function, and you might want to track Symfony's [Ladybug](https://www.drupal.org/node/1804998) which is under development for inclusing in Drupal 8.3.

Comment: Twig XDebug is another option. https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_xdebug